# Strange mysql issue with query optimizer

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have 2 mysql servers. 1 node is master and the other acting as slave, replicating from the master

The 2 nodes have identical data and schema.
However, 1 particular query is executed differently from mysql when run on both nodes

query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT t.*, COUNT(h.id)
                         FROM tags t
                         INNER JOIN tags2articles s
                         ON t.id = s.tag_id
                         INNER JOIN tag_hits h
                         ON h.id = s.tag_id
                         INNER JOIN articles art
                         ON art.id = s.`article_id`
                         WHERE art.source_id IN (SELECT id FROM feeds WHERE source_id = 15074)
                         AND time_added > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                         AND t.type = '1'
                         GROUP BY t.id
                         HAVING COUNT(h.id) > 4
                         ORDER BY COUNT(h.id) DESC
                         LIMIT 15
```

Below is the outpout from EXPLAIN query run on both nodes. Note that the master node is outputting
the correct one

output on master node

```
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type            | possible_keys               | key                 | key_len | ref            | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | art   | ALL             | PRIMARY                     | NULL                | NULL    | NULL           | 100270 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | s     | ref             | PRIMARY,FK_tags2articles    | FK_tags2articles    | 4       | art.id         |     12 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | h     | ref             | tags_hits_idx               | tags_hits_idx       | 4       | s.tag_id       |      1 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | t     | eq_ref          | PRIMARY,tags_type_idx       | PRIMARY             | 4       | s.tag_id       |      1 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | feeds | unique_subquery | PRIMARY,f_source_id_idx     | PRIMARY             | 4       | func           |      1 | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

output on slave node

+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------------------------------------

```
------+
| id | select_type        | table | type            | possible_keys               | key              | key_len | ref                | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | t     | ref             | PRIMARY,tags_type_idx       | tags_type_idx    |  2      | const              | 206432 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | h     | ref             | tags_hits_idx               | tags_hits_idx    | 4       | t.id               |      1 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | s     | ref             | PRIMARY,FK_tags2articles    | PRIMARY          | 4       | h.id               |      2 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | art   | eq_ref          | PRIMARY                     | PRIMARY          | 4       | s.article_id       |      1 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | feeds | unique_subquery | PRIMARY,f_source_id_idx     | PRIMARY          | 4       | func               |      1 | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I cannot understand why this discrepancy exists. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can have different statistics for indexes / keys and that causes differences in index usage. If possible (locks table, so not always recommended) run [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html) for all participating tables and then query plan is likely same.

Comment: The issue has emerged again after deleting a large number of entries on several of the tables involved in the query. I have tried both  analyze and optimize table, but this time nothing changed. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I need to run the OPTIMIZE TABLE clause 2 to 3 times in order for the statistics to be updated and the query to run correctly. The annoying thing is that this needs to be done regularly, every time that I delete a large portion of data and is really frustrating.